# the app crash when I tried to apply splash screen using a Launcher Theme

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm trying to apply a splash screen to my app, like this  [article](https://medium.com/@shishirthedev/the-right-way-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-android-acae0e52949a)says, there is two way and I picked the launched theme. after I followed all the step the crashed!
here is the resource drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_avatar_1" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

here is the style I used

```
    <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item
        name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_background
    </item>
</style>
```

the android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.remindme">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and finally this the splash screen activity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(Intent(this@SplashScreenActivity, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
```

and here is the logcat error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.remindme/com.example.remindme.SplashScreenActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_screen_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070097
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_screen_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070097
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:647)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:623)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:350)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
        at com.example.remindme.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.kt:10)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #8: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.verifyRequiredAttributes(BitmapDrawable.java:742)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:725)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:254)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:164)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540) 
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806) 
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458) 
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411) 
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:647) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:623) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:350) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105) 
        at com.example.remindme.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.kt:10) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Could you please provided some error log ?

Comment: edit your question with the crash log

Comment: it's there, I updated it

Comment: did you try to clean project and run?

Comment: can u please post 10th line of your SplashScreenActivity.kt

Comment: Does the `splash_screen_background` drawable resource actually exist? Is it named `splash_screen_background`? Is it in the `res/drawable` directory?

Comment: @Wahdat Kashmiri yes, it stills crashing

Comment: yes @Edric it is exist with the same name

Comment: <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_avatar_1" />

use src instead of srcCompat

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work. but I notice something, when I remove the the whole item of the bitmap leaving just the background item the app work find with a colored splash screen.
I guess the whole problem in the second <item>

Answer (score 0):

> srcCompat
> sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView. Allows the use of vector drawable when running on older versions of the platform.

you need to add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true to your build.gradle file and provide a vector image to srcCompact.

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
android {  
defaultConfig {  
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
 }  
}
```

update your resource drawable accordingly.

If you want use non-vector image you can use by replacing app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_avatar_1" to android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar_1".

Answer (score 0):

Most reliable way to use [vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) to project is to use `app:scrCompact= "@drawable/ic_avatar_1"` because while building the apk, Android gradle will generate lots of png files for different screen sizes such as (ldpi | mdpi | tvdpi | hdpi | xhdpi | xxhdpi | xxxhdpi) which leads to increase the size of apk.

I'm not sure but add vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true to your build.gradle file & check.

```
 // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
android {  defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  }}
```